# Updating timestamps on attaching/detaching Eloquent relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4, and have 2 models:

```
class Asset extends \Eloquent {
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }
}

class Product extends \Eloquent {
    public function assets() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Asset');
    }
}
```

`Product` has the standard timestamps on it (`created_at`, `updated_at`) and I'd like to update the `updated_at` field of the `Product` when I attach/detach an `Asset`.

I tried this on the `Asset` model:

```
class Asset extends \Eloquent {
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

...but that did nothing at all (apparently). **Edit**: apparently this is for updating timestamps on the pivot table, not for updating them on the relation's own table (ie. updates `assets_products.updated_at`, not `products.updated_at`).

I then tried this on the `Asset` model:

```
class Asset extends \Eloquent {
    protected $touches = [ 'products' ];

    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }
}
```

...which works, but then breaks my seed which calls `Asset::create([ ... ]);` because apparently Laravel tries to call `->touchOwners()` on the relation without checking if it's `null`:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::touchOwners() in /projectdir/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 1583

The code I'm using to add/remove `Asset`s is this:

```
Product::find( $validId )->assets()->attach( $anotherValidId );
Product::find( $validId )->assets()->detach( $anotherValidId );
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I suppose you've to add the ```withTimestamps()``` on the ```assets()``` method. ```withTimestamps()``` shall work as you can figure out here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/109

Comment: @arjan the timestamp I wish to update is on the `Product`, not on the pivot table

Comment: Which subversion of laravel 4 are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it manually using `touch` method:

```
$product = Product::find($validId);
$product->assets()->attach($anotherValidId);
$product->touch();
```

But if you don't want to do it manually each time you can simplify this creating method in your `Product` model this way:

```
public function attachAsset($id)
{
    $this->assets()->attach($id);
    $this->touch();
}
```

And now you can use it this way:

```
Product::find($validId)->attachAsset($anotherValidId);
```

The same you can of course do for detach action.

And I noticed you have one relation `belongsToMany` and the other `hasMany` - it should be rather `belongsToMany` in both because it's many to many relationship

**EDIT**

If you would like to use it in many models, you could create trait or create another base class that extends Eloquent with the following method:

```
public function attach($id, $relationship =  null)
{
    $relationship = $relationship ?: $this->relationship;
    $this->{$relationship}()->attach($id);
    $this->touch();
}
```

Now, if you need this functionality you just need to extend from another base class (or use trait), and now you can add to your `Product` class one extra property:

```
private $relationship = 'assets';
```

Now you could use:

```
Product::find($validId)->attach($anotherValidId);
```

or

```
Product::find($validId)->attach($anotherValidId, 'assets');
```

if you need to attach data with updating `updated_at` field. The same of course you need to repeat for detaching.

Comment: Good spot on the HasMany - that's a typo :-) If at all possible I'd like to avoid creating a helper method, because I'll probably be doing a similar thing with a few other models, although if there's no other way then it's a valid workaround

Comment: @Joe I don't know if it can be done other way, it seems it's impossible to track attach/detach actions using event listener but maybe I'm wrong or someone else will find better solution

Comment: @Joe I've updated my answer with possible solution to use it in many models

Answer (score 1):

From the [code source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L524), you need to set `$touch` to false when creating a new instance of the related model:

```
Asset::create(array(),array(),false);
```

or use:

```
$asset = new Asset;
// ... 
$asset->setTouchedRelations([]);
$asset->save();
```

Comment: It appears that that `::create()` method is on the `BelongsToMany` relation, not on the `Model`, so you can't just pass extra parameters through to `Asset::create()`. The second option may work, although I'd rather keep using `::create()` if possible

Comment: sorry, I did not understand your question correctly, apparently @Marcin Nabiałek's answer is a good workaround

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

Create a `BaseModel` that extends Eloquent, making a simple adjustment to the `create` method:

**BaseModel.php**:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
    /**
     * Save a new model and return the instance, passing along the
     * $options array to specify the behavior of 'timestamps' and 'touch'
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return static
     */
    public static function create(array $attributes, array $options = array())
    {
        $model = new static($attributes);
        $model->save($options);
        return $model;
    }
}
```

Have your `Asset` and `Product` models (and others, if desired) extend `BaseModel` rather than `Eloquent`, and set the `$touches` attribute:

**Asset.php** (and other models):

```
class Asset extends BaseModel {
    protected $touches = [ 'products' ];
    ...
```

**In your seeders**, set the 2nd parameter of `create` to an array which specifies `'touch'` as `false`:

```
Asset::create([...],['touch' => false])
```

---

### Explanation:

Eloquent's [`save()` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1418) accepts an (optional) array of options, in which you can specify two flags: `'timestamps'` and `'touch'`. If `touch` is set to `false`, then Eloquent will do no touching of related models, regardless of any `$touches` attributes you've specified on your models. This is all built-in behavior for Eloquent's `save()` method.

The problem is that Eloquent's [`create()` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L522) doesn't accept any options to pass along to `save()`. By extending Eloquent (with a `BaseModel`) to accept the `$options` array as the 2nd attribute, and pass it along to `save()`, you can now use those two options when you call `create()` on all your models which extend `BaseModel`.

Note that the `$options` array is optional, so doing this won't break any other calls to `create()` you might have in your code.

Comment: This problem did not exist on Laravel/Framework version `4.2.6`, but does exist on `4.2.11`. To me it seems that Laravel should be able to detect this automatically, right? In other words, isn't this just a bug?